# MySQL query that combines two tables and two columns in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I'm trying to write an SQL query that combines two tables and two columns in one of the tables. So, I have two tables

Table: `Items`

```
ID          Material           Shape

1           glass              jar
2           plastic            bottle
3           cardboard          box
4           glass              bottle
```

Table: `Diary`

```
ItemID      UserID      Quantity

2           1           1
1           1           3
3           1           2
2           1           5
4           1           1
```

Expected output where `UserID = 1` (sorted by `combined quantity`):

```
Combined column values       Combined quantity

plastic bottle               6
glass jar                    3
cardboard box                2
glass bottle                 1
```

Could someone direct me the right way?

Comment: JOIN (or LEFT JOIN), GROUP BY, SUM()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a `join` and `group by`:

```
select concat_ws(' ', i.material, i.shape) as combined,
       sum(d.quantity) as combined_quantity
from items i left join
     diary d
     on d.itemId = i.id
group by combined
order by combined_quantity desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select Material+SPACE(1)+ SHAPE [Combined column values ], 
SUM(QUANTITY) [Combined quantity]
from Items 
left join diary on Items.itemiD = diary.itemID  
GROUP BY ITEMS.itemiD, Material, SHAPE
```

**Output**

[image]